# Does [t] become [g] due to anticipatory assimilation?

Tags: consonants, velar

In this particular rule [t] -> [g]/_ V [+velar] (because of anticipatory assimilation)
I'm unsure of how to actually write this in the most efficient way.

I want to know that if [t] changes to [g] due 'anticipatory assimilation'?

Comment: Are you asking about RP specifically, English more generally, or about any languages which have voiced and unvoiced alveolar stops? Oops sorry I thought you were asking about [t] vs [d] ... this is actually more interesting (-:

Comment: It can be [anticipatory assimilation at a distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(linguistics)#Anticipatory_assimilation_at_a_distance).

Comment: Are you asking how to formulate the rule using commonly used features? Or are you asking if 'velar harmony' is a common phonological phenomenon in child RP? Or are you asking the phenomenon of velar harmony can be used to explain the data you have? If it's one of the first two I'd change the title of the post. If it's the third I'd make that clearer in the post itself.

Comment: I see. But naming the process and formulating a rule to describe the process and the environment in which it occurs are two different things. You can call something 'velar harmony' or 'anticipatory assimilation', but those names won't let people know the precise nature of the phonological generalization in question. In other words, coming up with an appropriately descriptive name for the process won't change what information you need to provide in the rule, so it won't affect how efficient the formulation is.

Comment: Why did you maim the question? It was better than a one-liner.

Comment: I was editing it, accidentally saved. Have re-done now. :-)